# Resizing Image Not working

Tags: java, image-resizing

I've made a Button class which allows me to have buttons (Kind of obvious). But in my button class, I'm using an image to display the button on the screen. I got that to work, but I want to resize the image to the size of the button.

My "Image Resizer" works flawlessly, but when I try to resize the button, the button doesn't show up. I don't get any errors.

Here's my Button class:

```
private String text;
private int size = 0;
private BufferedImage buttonHD;

public Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, int size) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    this.size = size;
    buttonHD = Renderer.resizeImage(Images.button, x, y, width, height);
}

public Button setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    return this;
}

public void drawButton(Graphics g, int xoffset, int yoffset) {
    int xx = x + xoffset;
    int yy = y + yoffset;

    if(!MouseInput.MOUSE.intersects(this)) {
        g.drawImage(buttonHD, x, y, width, height, null);
    } else if(MouseInput.MOUSE.intersects(this)){
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    Renderer.drawText(text, g, xoffset, yoffset, size);//Draws button text
}
```

The original image that I'm resizing is stored into my Images class as:

```
public static BufferedImage button;
```

Here's my "Button Resizer" method:

```
public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage origImg, int x, int y, int initWidth, int initHeight) {
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(initWidth, initHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(origImg, x, y, initWidth, initHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}
```

The way I'm using these buttons are in `ScreenState` classes. Each class representing as each state. The buttons are set in there and are loaded up by the class's constructor.

The buttons do work as they should, but the images just don't show up. If more code is needed, just let me know and I'll provide you with it.

I've been trying to fix this problem, but had no luck. If someone could just hint out as to where my problem is or maybe have a solution, that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This function resizes the `BufferedImage` to the given `width` and `height`:

```
public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
    // calculate the scale factor
    double xScale = width / (double) image.getWidth();
    double yScale = height / (double) image.getHeight();
    // create the object that will contain the resized image
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // resize the image
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) resizedImage.getGraphics();
    g.scale(xScale, yScale);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    // return the resized image
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Then simply use it:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton
{
    private BufferedImage image;


    public MyButton() {
        image = resizeImage(ImageIO.read(IMAGE_PATH), BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    }


    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

`IMAGE_PATH` is the `File` where your image is located, `BUTTON_WIDTH` and `BUTTON_HEIGHT` is your button dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Rectangles (Button class extends Rectangle) for the buttons and not JButton. Also using MouseAdapter in a separate class (Where I check to see if the button was clicked).

Comment: You want a Button filled with an image (a resized image) if mouse is over it and a dark gray button when mouse exit the button itself?